# Does 12 10 minute cardio sessions equal one 120 minute session?

Tags: exercise, cardio, calories, health

If I jump rope and achieve a heart rate of 150 bpm for 10 minutes and I do this 12 times a day is that going to burn an equal number of calories and strengthen my cardio system as much as jumping rope with a heart rate of 150 bpm for 120 minutes?

Also, how long would it take me to do 12 10 minute sessions? i.e. how long does it take for my body to warm up to 150 bpm?

Comment: Why do you need to know that information? Sometimes people ask the wrong questions in this SE - which is why I'm curious where your120 minute reference comes from

Comment: I am confused why you are asking why I need to know this. I didn't think there had to be a specific reason to post a question in SE. My 120 minute reference comes from a number I thought would be a good example of a long cardio session. I wanted to be clear that the total time was the same.

Comment: Working for 120 minutes straight would be more beneficial as your muscles will be under constant stress as your body becomes tired thus pushing to work harder. The only time shorter cardio is recommended is when doing HIIT but if you're planning to do the same pace split up in to 12 times a day it's not going to help you as much as a long session

Comment: There doesn't have to be a specific reason. However it seems like quite a random comparison. If it's a purely academic question, never mind. But I find that many people here overcomplicate things and focus on the wrong things and ask the wrong questions which is why I wondered why you asked such an unusual question. Again, nothing wrong with it, but perhaps there is something more to it that yields a more fruitful discussion and perhaps helps you improve your training more

Comment: @Twyxz - Not necessarily. There might be good reasons to do shorter, quality sessions where form and effort do not degrade over time. I agree that one shouldn't *only* do the split workouts, but "more beneficial" depends on the intended purpose of the workout.

Comment: @Raditz_35 No I just wanted to know if anyone knew of any specific differences but didn't want to ask is exercising for a long time the same as exercising a bunch of times for less time because the first thing someone would have said was well it depends on heart rate etc.

Answer (score 1):

It yould burn the same number of calories, or close to that. Based on the assumption that you start with the goal bpm in the shorter sessions.

Concerning the strengthening of your cardio system - no. I assume that 150bpm is no where neary your max HR. General if you do shorter sessions you have to go harder to get a similar effect for your cardio system, but short sessions will never fully mimic the effects of long training sessions.